# JQuery Library Pack

Tags: fancybox, drop-down-menu

How to use Jquery libraries or how to use fancy box using JQuery.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, SantoshP.

Answer (score 1):

#### Generally speaking...

Most jQuery plugins are used merely by referencing the plugin source file *after* the jQuery source, and then calling the plugin method on a selector:

```
$("a.something").plugin();
```

This will vary from plugin to plugin, so be sure to consult the relevant documentation. Some plugins will accept arguments in JSON form:

```
$("a.something").plugin({ 'foo':'bar', 'fizz':'buzz' });
```

Again, consult the relevant documentation.

#### Fancybox, specifically...

You can find the **fancybox** documentation online at http://fancybox.net/howto where they give great details about how to implement it in your project. They finish off their how-to with the following example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* This is basic - uses default settings */
  $("a#single_image").fancybox();
    
  /* Using custom settings */
  $("a#inline").fancybox({ 'hideOnContentClick':true });

  $("a.group").fancybox({ 'speedIn':600, 'speedOut':200, 'overlayShow':false });

});
```

Note the similarities between this, and the aforementioned general rules.